# "someone satisfied /pleased / ??? with the situation" expression - is the correct way to say that?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality, phrase-requests, writing-style

I have the following phrase:
A student just learnt that he failed an important exam. To what extent do you think he is satisfied/pleased/??? with this situation?

I need that the answer to this question will be "not at all".

What is the best way to express this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably .. *to what extent do you think he is worried about this situation?*

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention. I need that the answer would be "not at all"

Comment: "How pleased will he be about the situation?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the answer right there. He will not be pleased at all if he was hoping to pass the course. Using "To what extent" is an antiquated way of saying "How" or "How much" but is still OK. "How satisfied will he be?"

"To what extent do you think he will be pleased with this situation?"

"Not at all."